# How to track Emails sent to popular Email providers?

Tags: email, gmail

There are few services that let you know whether someone opened your email or not and even how many times and when! As a reference I should link to [MailTrack](https://mailtrack.io/en/) and [Mixmax](https://mixmax.com/feature-spotlight-email-tracking/)

I wonder how to detect when someone opens an email?

**[Update]**

As @GabrielCliseru said: most Email providers scrub JavaScript from HTML Emails so this one is off the chart

> Gmail strips out any content between script tags before displaying
>   the message. [Source](https://superuser.com/questions/430562/does-gmail-or-any-other-popular-webmail-service-scrub-javascript-from-html-email)

Comment: Emails are meant to send messages, not to execute code to look fancy. If you want the recipients to execute the code, send them a link to a web page.

Answer (score 1):

The javascript code sent inside an email is not executed. This is a security limitation.

Comment: I see some app called mail track it let me know if some one read my mail it uses iframe but i want to see is there any way for some one to hack me with email or what else can be done tanks a lot

Comment: I updated my question to be more clear. Also mentioned you in an update. Although to my knowledge this is not an answer and should posted as a comment.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do exactly?
You want to send a jquery code by email?
You can do it simple.
Or for more sure, you can put it in a Text file and attach it

Comment: no i want to do something with javascript in email like a timer or etc

Comment: It's not possible for couple reasons.
1. Security.
2. Accessing to the data.
I think its not possible.

Comment: see the app mail track it some how use this and tell you when your mail opened so there should be something or i'm wrong

Comment: Yes it works properly. But its not for common Emails nor web mails like these. Its for outlook or other Email apps. 
Gmail & Ymail & Hotmail is not supporting that in free versions. If you upgrade them to Plus versions this feature will be available for you. If it has another way, i dont know unfortunately.

Comment: i'm trying to find how it works tell me if you know

Comment: JavaScript will not work inside HTML Emails as you and @GabrielCliseru already said. But I need to Improve this question so I can post again.Anyway what you wrote is not an answer to the question so please Edit it to fit. Thanks